# Get full class name from table name in nhibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Using NHibernate, and in my code, I know what the table name is e.g. "Site" - but I need to find out what the full class name is just by knowing this e.g. "MyApp.Models.Site"

I need to be able to do this programmatically. Is this possible? If so how?

I'm using FluentNHibernate if this helps.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i'm not sure what you're asking for, but if you want to find which entity maps table, you can use this piece of code

```
 configuration.ClassMappings.Where(x => x.Table.Name == "Site").First().EntityName
```

Comment: Looks promising but how do I get 'configuration'?

Comment: before you build session factory you have to configure nhibernate, when you're configuring with fluent you can build nh configuration.